# What's required for Windows to update the "file modified" timestamp?

Tags: c#, windows, file, timestamp

Obviously it gets updated during a write operation, but are there any non-destructive operations that also force an update?  Basically looking to be able to do the equivalent of the *nix touch command, but in C# programmatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the function SetFileTime (C++) or File.SetLastWriteTime (C#) to set the last write time to the current time.

Comment: Excellent, thanks much!  I figured it would be simple, but I'm still learning my way around the .Net framework...  Sometimes even simple things can be hard to find...  :)

Answer (score 4):

[System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(string path, DateTime lastWriteTime);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

From .NET, use the LastWriteTime property of the FileSystemInfo object.  There is, in fact, a complete Touch app in [example of that property in the MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx)