# Finding out the Datetime value in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my vb.net winform application, I am moving the file from one folder to another. I need to store the datetimevalue when the transfer has been done. Later I need to show this DateTime value in my Grid.

Here is the code i have written, but not able to store the datetime value.

```
 Public Shared processedTime as DateTime
 Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")
 Dim ioLine As String
 Dim ioLines As String
 ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
ioLines = ioLine
While Not ioLine = ""
  ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
  ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine
End While
Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")
ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)
ioFile.Close()
ioWriter.Close()
processedTime = Date.Now()
```

Comment: We probably need to see some more code because from what you have posted you just declare a variable with a datetime data type and assign a date to it - not much can go wrong there

Comment: Once you have determined the processedTime, my question is *where* do you want to store it?  As mika alluded to below, why not just store the last modified time of the new.csv file in the datagridview?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx

It is in C# but it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Without details about the grid data source (filesystem, database ?), I'd say it is easiest to persist the transfer datetime value to the file itself. In fact, in the example code, `"C:\new.csv"` should have the correct "last modified" timestamp.

To read "last modified", use [GetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx):

```
Dim dt As DateTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("C:\new.csv")
```

To update "last modified", use [SetLastWriteTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime.aspx):

```
System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime("C:\new.csv", DateTime.Now())
```

#### See also:

> [What's required for Windows to update the “file modified” timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306562/whats-required-for-windows-to-update-the-file-modified-timestamp)

Comment: After I store the Filetransfer datetime value, i need to display this datetime value on the DataGridView. Nowhere I connect to database.